# Android Okhttp hides content encoding : gzip in the header

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

From the official documentation of okhttp it states that it handled transparent gzip process. But my doubt is in my header i cannot see the content header, i tried retrieve the header `content-encoding` from the response it gives null. But i didn't add any additional header for encoding.
I tried the same request through `RestClient` from that i can see the header `content-encoding:   gzip`

```
fun getOkHttpClient(myInterceptor: MyInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
    val okHttpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(myInterceptor)
    return okHttpClientBuilder.build()
}
```

Can anyone suggest me what may be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a feature:

> If transparent compression was used, OkHttp will drop the corresponding response headers `Content-Encoding` and `Content-Length` because they don’t apply to the decompressed response body.

[source](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/980053f17d3027455c3d611081cdc87b99175799/docs/calls.md)

Comment: Also, you can use `Response.networkResponse.request` to see what was sent on the wire.